# Retrieving old Check-box array

Tags: laravel, laravel-5.1, laravel-5

I have a checkbox array that has its values stored as JSON in a database, I want to get the old value or the stored value in the database. here is the code I wrote.

It did not work as I expected, is there a best practice to deal with this issue?

```
<?php $savedDevices = json_decode(Auth::user()->devices, true);?>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[Android Phone]" value="1" {{(old('devices') !== null && array_key_exists("Android Tablet", old('devices')) ||array_key_exists("Android Tablet", $savedDevices) )?"checked":""}}> Android Phone </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[Android Tablet]" value="1"  {{(old('devices') !== null && array_key_exists("Android Tablet", old('devices')) ||array_key_exists("Android Tablet", $savedDevices) )?"checked":""}}> Android Tablet </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[iPhone]" value="1" {{(old('devices') !== null && array_key_exists("iPhone", old('devices')) ||array_key_exists("iPhone", $savedDevices) )?"checked":""}}> iPhone </label>
<input type="checkbox" name="devices[iPad]" value="1" {{(old('devices') !== null && array_key_exists("iPad", old('devices')) ||array_key_exists("iPad", $savedDevices) )?"checked":""}}> iPad </label>
```

Answer (score 0):

If your decoded json may be like below then

```
 $savedDevices = [
  'phone'  =>'yes',
  'tablet' => 'yes',
   'iphone' => 'no'
                   ] 

<label>
           Phone :<input type="checkbox"
        {{($savedDevices->phone == "yes") ? "checked":""  }} name="phone"> 
  Tablet :<input type="checkbox"
            {{($savedDevices->tablet == "yes") ? "checked":""  }} name="tablet">
 Iphone :<input type="checkbox"
            {{($savedDevices->iphone == "yes") ? "checked":""  }} name="iphone">
    </label>
```

According to above $savedDevices data first two check boxes are checked because the value = yes and iphone checkbox is unchecked because its value not equal to yes.

now if you want to change the values of phone and tablet,uncheck the boxes and submit the values

Comment: Thanks, the problem how to preserve the old value during validation, this solution will not show the old value

Comment: Are you creating the form or updating the form

Comment: if (!$validator->passes()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($validator->errors());
        }

Comment: the form is updating

Answer (score 0):

when you use withInput($request->all()) then old can be used in forms.
In your controller

```
$validator = \Validator::make($data, Distributors::rules($request->id));
if (!$validator->passes()) {
            return redirect()->back()->withInput($request->all())->withErrors($validator->errors());
    }
```

in forms

```
$savedDevices = [
  'phone'  =>'yes',
  'tablet' => 'yes',
   'iphone' => 'no'
                   ] 

<label>
           Phone :<input type="checkbox"
        {{(old('phone') == 'yes') ? "checked":""  }} name="phone"> 
  Tablet :<input type="checkbox"
            {{(old('tablet') == "yes") ? "checked":""  }} name="tablet">
 Iphone :<input type="checkbox"
            {{(old('iphone') == "yes") ? "checked":""  }} name="iphone">
    </label>
```

Note: in old('name of you check box must use')

Answer (score 0):

1. ->First when you click on edit update form loads.
2. ->Then after loading the form,old input is null so database value is checked
3. ->after submitting the form,if validation fails then redirect back to form with old input

> ```
>   Phone :<input type="checkbox"
>               @if(old('phone') !=null)
>             {{(old('phone') == 'on') ? "checked":""  }}
>               @else
>            {{($savedDevices->tablet == "on") ? "checked":""  }}
>     @endif
>      name="phone">
> ```

Comment: This solution works for sure, my point is can we use array devices[Android Phone] instead of having each element alone. I do not want to spend much time on it but I just wondering

Answer (score 0):

Here is what worked for me

```
    <?php $savedDevices = json_decode(Auth::user()->devices, true);?>
                            {{$checked = ""}}
                            <!-- Check if it is a post back-->
                            <?php $postBack = old()?>
                            @if(empty($postBack))
                                <!-- First Request, get data from the DB -->
                                @if(array_key_exists('Android Phone',$savedDevices))
                                    <?php $checked = "checked";?>
                                @endif
                            @else
                                 <!-- Update attempt has happend -->
                                @if(array_key_exists('Android Phone',old('devices',[])))
                                    <?php $checked = "checked";?>
                                @else
                                    <?php $checked = "";?>
                                @endif
                            @endif
                        <label>
                            <input type="checkbox" name="devices[Android Phone]" value="1" {{$checked}} > Android Phone </label>
```

Answer (score -1):

Try this

```
<?php $old_devices = old('devices', []); ?>

<input type="checkbox" name="devices[Android Phone]" value="1" {{array_key_exists("Android Tablet", $old_devices) || array_key_exists("Android Tablet", $savedDevices) ? "checked":""}}> Android Phone </label>
```

Comment: I tried, it throw an exception when old does not exist this why I check if it exists

Comment: strange the old helper never throw exception if an input not exists, it will return null

https://laravel.com/docs/5.2/requests#old-input

Comment: what is the version of laravel you are using?

Comment: array_key_exists is the one that raise the exception because old return null

Comment: I am.using the latest version

Comment: Are you using middleware web in your routes